# Songkick widget not displaying right when pasted into HTML on Tumblr

Tags: javascript, tumblr, songkick

I used a auto generated HTML code from Songkick and I put it straight into the HTML on my Tumblr website and its not showing anything but the title.
You can look at it here http://yuniwamusic.com/shows

This is the code I used

```
<a href="http://www.songkick.com/artists/8434448" class="songkick-widget" data-theme="light" data-track-button="on" data-detect-style="true" data-background-color="transparent">Yuni Wa tour dates</a>
```

Comment: You should include a reproducible code example in your question

Comment: <a href="http://www.songkick.com/artists/8434448" class="songkick-widget" data-theme="light" data-track-button="on" data-detect-style="true" data-background-color="transparent">Yuni Wa tour dates</a>
<script src="//widget.songkick.com/widget.js"></script>

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: According to the docs: http://support.songkick.com/customer/portal/articles/2091030-website-widget-101?b_id=9837 It sounds like you're missing the actual script to run the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You need to open your file on localhost, not directly from your disc. :)